# Java Rock Paper Scissors - Everything Is a Tie

Tags: java

I am working on a project for an introductory CompSci course in java and I am stuck. We have to fill out the methods for a rock, paper, scissor game called stick, fire, water. I thought I filled it out correctly, but every time I run it, my program says it is a tie. It displays both my choice and the computer choice, but it says it is a tie and it doesn't increment the rounds played (or either my score or the computer's score, but since it is a tie that would not happen anyways, although I am sure it is still messed up).

````
/* This class ecapsulates the state and logic required to play the 
   Stick, Water, Fire game. The game is played between a user and the computer. 
   A user enters their choice, either S for stick, F for fire, W for water, and 
   the computer generates one of these choices at random- all equally likely.
   The two choices are evaluated according to the rules of the game and the winner
   is declared.
   
   Rules of the game:
   S beats W
   W beats F
   F beats S
   no winner on a tie.
   
   Each round is executed by the playRound method. In addition to generating the computer 
   choice and evaluating the two choices, this class also keeps track of the user and computer
   scores, the number of wins, and the total number of rounds that have been played. In the case
   of a tie, neither score is updated, but the number of rounds is incremented.
   
   NOTE: Do not modify any of the code that is provided in the starter project. Additional instance variables and methods 
   are not required to make the program work correctly, but you may add them if you wish as long as
   you fulfill the project requirements.
   
*/
public class StickWaterFireGame {

      // TODO 1: Declare private instance variables here:
     
   Random rand = new Random();
   int numRounds = 0;
   int playerScore = 0;
   int computerScore = 0;
   boolean playerWins = false;
   boolean isTie = false;
   
  /*  This constructor assigns the member Random variable, rand, to 
   *  a new, unseeded Random object.
   *  It also initializes the instance variables to their default values:
   *  rounds, player and computer scores will be 0, the playerWins and isTie
   *  variables should be set to false.
   */ 
   public StickWaterFireGame() {
   // TODO 2: Implement this method.
  
   Random rand = new Random();
   numRounds = 0;
   playerScore = 0;
   computerScore = 0;
   playerWins = false;
   isTie = false;
  
   }
  
  /*  This constructor assigns the member Random variable, rand, to 
   *  a new Random object using the seed passed in.
   *  It also initializes the instance variables to their default values:
   *  rounds, player and computer scores will be 0, the playerWins and isTie
   *  variables should be set to false.
   */    
   public StickWaterFireGame(int seed) {
   // TODO 3: Implement this method.
  
   Random rand = new Random(seed);
   numRounds = 0;
   playerScore = 0;
   computerScore = 0;
   playerWins = false;
   isTie = false;
  
   }   

  /*  This method returns true if the inputStr passed in is
   *  either "S", "W", or "F", false otherwise.
   *  Note that the input can be upper or lower case.
   */ 
   public boolean isValidInput(String inputStr) {
   // TODO 4: Implement this method.
   
   if (inputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("S") || inputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("W") || inputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("F")) {
      return true;
      }
      
   else {
      return false; 
      
      }
   }
   
    // Returns the choice of the computer for the most recent round of play
   public String getComputerChoice(){
   // TODO 5: Implement this method.
             
    return getRandomChoice();
   }
            
   // Returns true if the player has won the last round, false otherwise.    
   public boolean playerWins(){
   // TODO 6: Implement this method.
      
      if (playerWins) {
      return true;
      }
      
      else {
      return false;
      }
   }
   
   // Returns the player's cumulative score.    
   public int getPlayerScore(){
   // TODO 7: Implement this method.
      return playerScore;
   }
   
   // Returns the computer's cumulative score.   
   public int getComputerScore(){
   // TODO 8: Implement this method.
      return computerScore;
   }
   
   // Returns the total nuber of rounds played.   
   public int getNumRounds(){
   // TODO 9: Implement this method.
      return numRounds;
   }

   // Returns true if the player and computer have the same score on the last round, false otherwise.    
   public boolean isTie(){
   // TODO 10: Implement this method.
      
      if (computerScore == playerScore) {
         return true;
         }
         
      else {
      return false;
      }
      
   }

  /*  This "helper" method uses the instance variable of Random to generate an integer
   *  which it then maps to a String: "S", "W", "F", which is returned.
   *  This method is called by the playRound method.
   */
   private String getRandomChoice() {
   // TODO 11: Implement this method.
    
    String randomChoice = "";
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomInput = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;
    
    if (randomInput == 1) {
      randomChoice = "S";
      }
      
    if (randomInput == 2) {
      randomChoice = "W";
      }
      
    if (randomInput == 3) {
      randomChoice = "F";
      }
   
      return randomChoice;
   }

 /*  This method carries out a single round of play of the SWF game. 
   *  It calls the isValidInput method and the getRandomChoice method. 
   *  It implements the rules of the game and updates the instance variables
   *  according to those rules.
   */
   public void playRound(String playerChoice) {
   // TODO 12: Implement this method.
  
   int numRounds = 0;
   int playerScore = 0;
   int computerScore = 0;
   boolean playerWins = false;
   boolean isTie = false;
   String computerChoice = getRandomChoice();
   
   if (!isValidInput(playerChoice)) {
      ++computerScore;
      ++numRounds;
      }
      
      else {
         
         if (computerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase(playerChoice)) {
            ++numRounds;
            }
            
         if (computerChoice.equals("S") && playerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("W")) {
            ++computerScore;
            ++numRounds;
            }
            
         if (computerChoice.equals("S") && playerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("F")) {
            playerWins = true;
            ++playerScore;
            ++numRounds;
            }
           
         if (computerChoice.equals("W") && playerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) {
            playerWins = true;
            ++playerScore;
            ++numRounds;
            }
            
         if (computerChoice.equals("W") && playerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("F")) {
            ++computerScore;
            ++numRounds;
            }
            
         if (computerChoice.equals("F") && playerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) {
            ++computerScore;
            ++numRounds;
            }
            
         if (computerChoice.equals("F") && playerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("W")) {
            playerWins = true;
            ++playerScore;
            ++numRounds;
            }
          }
        }
      } ```
````

Comment: You are redeclaring numRounds etc. in the method `playRound` instead of just setting them to  0.  They are shadowing other variables.  I don't think that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this method. You are redelaring three variables when you set them to 0.  I think  you just want to assign them.

```
  public void playRound(String playerChoice) {
   // TODO 12: Implement this method.
  
   int numRounds = 0;   
   int playerScore = 0;
   int computerScore = 0;
   boolean playerWins = false;
   boolean isTie = false;
   String computerChoice = getRandomChoice();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous suspicious things about your code, but the specific issues you describe are likely related to the fact that your `playRound()` method declares local variables shadowing most of the class's instance variables:

> ```
>    int numRounds = 0;
>    int playerScore = 0;
>    int computerScore = 0;
>    boolean playerWins = false;
>    boolean isTie = false;
> ```

That method manipulates those local variables rather than the like-named instance variables, and the effects can be seen only inside that method, for the duration of one execution of it.  Just removing those local-variable declarations should move you forward.